# How do I modify query strings in the URL to make them more user friendly

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file, which removes the .php extension, and removes the slashes after the remainder, if it isn't a directory. However, I would like to modify this to take change query strings as well.

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
RewriteBase /

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

I would like to change {root}/file?id=1 to /file/1
and
I would like to change {root}/directory/file?id=1 to {root}/directory/file/1

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert these 2 new rules **in the end**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/$2?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**PS: Also make sure to use `L` flag in all of your `RewriteRule` lines above.**